# How to get a list of freeswitch registered accounts

Tags: freeswitch

I am developing a pjsip application. I am using Freeswitch as SIP server. (this is VOIP)

Is there a command in fs-cli that lists all the registered users in Freeswitch. I need something like that to know which accounts are in a conference and so on.

I am aware of this site: http://voicebundle.com/getting-familiar-with-the-fs_cli-interface-freeswitch-command-line, but it doesnt give me the command i need.

Answer (score 16):

Found the answer! In fs_cli typ:

```
sofia status profile internal reg
```

This command will list every registered  account in Freeswitch

Answer (score 13):

And for a lesser detailed version you also have :

`show registrations`

Comment: Thanks @real_yggdrasil I earned a few more SF privileges thanks to your upvote :-), including the Comment one.